# [Python]: How to convert Convert key value string without quotes in string to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Scenario:

1.How to convert the below key value string pair without quotes to dictionary.

```
employee='{"Priority":{0:"High"},"Age":{range(0,5):"high"}}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using eval to execute the expression will return the dictionary

```
employee = '{"Priority":{0:"High"},"Age":{range(0,5):"high"}}'

dict_ = eval(employee)
print(dict_)  # {'Priority': {0: 'High'}, 'Age': {range(0, 5): 'high'}}
print(type(dict_))  # <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: At least use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @DeepSpace `ast.literal_eval` will not work for a function call, such as `range`.  This answer may result in arbitrary code execution, but the question effectively invites one so...